# Why are the vertical lines of plt.grid() missing in a plot from Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a `Pandas` dataframe which has 10 numerical columns and I want to plot all of them in 5 by 2 layout. However, the figure I am getting has the vertical lines of the grids missing. As an example, I am aiming for something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size = (50,10)))
df.plot(subplots = True, layout = (5,2))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This code will (correctly) produce the following figure

[image]

Now, here comes my problem. I have the following code:

```
ff_intraday_alldays_corr_df.plot(subplots = True, layout = (5,2), figsize = (20,10), sharex = False)

plt.grid(True, axis = 'both')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

From this code, I get the following output:

[image]

Notice that the vertical lines are missing although I am explicitly telling `pyplot` to draw the grid on both axis. What am I doing wrong? I will attach a `to_dict()` version of the head of data frame for reproducibility below.

---------- HEAD of DATAFRAME -------

```
[In]: ff_intraday_alldays_corr_df.head().to_dict()

[Out]:
{'CMA_HML': {Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:00:00'): 0.44795094851406814,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:05:00'): 0.38428983506941855,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:10:00'): 0.41193874696647115,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:15:00'): 0.4293209374846741,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:20:00'): 0.43522783548870514},
 'CMA_MOM': {Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:00:00'): 0.05347989373858762,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:05:00'): -0.011608270033198973,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:10:00'): -0.027402429382035524,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:15:00'): -0.019610957532699484,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:20:00'): -0.007050143600690808},
 'CMA_RMW': {Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:00:00'): 0.20556028201595988,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:05:00'): 0.09653225241133827,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:10:00'): 0.11139372351072817,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:15:00'): 0.11426743038168899,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:20:00'): 0.11796468233334897},
 'CMA_SMB': {Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:00:00'): 0.1517609108883879,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:05:00'): 0.056390472251534485,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:10:00'): 0.09804054386505605,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:15:00'): 0.11551034194086211,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:20:00'): 0.12670084298270848},
 'HML_MOM': {Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:00:00'): -0.2978307580920829,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:05:00'): -0.2560333041281664,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:10:00'): -0.27203290482545234,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:15:00'): -0.2702720485891392,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:20:00'): -0.25899000452295107},
 'HML_RMW': {Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:00:00'): 0.17496766686559892,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:05:00'): 0.05867960946753955,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:10:00'): 0.07492619768022696,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:15:00'): 0.07544496840758017,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:20:00'): 0.07378940456925964},
 'HML_SMB': {Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:00:00'): 0.11783436515538953,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:05:00'): 0.0572659935968401,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:10:00'): 0.10589632150389904,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:15:00'): 0.13172904632035068,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:20:00'): 0.15248571968608735},
 'MOM_RMW': {Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:00:00'): 0.09347437113499303,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:05:00'): 0.10238296372223599,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:10:00'): 0.09467287450167983,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:15:00'): 0.08173228399896171,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:20:00'): 0.08894348736883101},
 'MOM_SMB': {Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:00:00'): 0.11279955572946082,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:05:00'): -0.01565427697073142,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:10:00'): -0.019023170042160316,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:15:00'): -0.0055759975445638255,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:20:00'): -0.0025691959978936586},
 'RMW_SMB': {Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:00:00'): -0.020075628073247538,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:05:00'): -0.16367953534291818,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:10:00'): -0.13591209255538989,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:15:00'): -0.14175163614235164,
  Timestamp('2020-08-17 10:20:00'): -0.14258055578226198}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution using Plotly:

```py
# Import packages
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create data table (replace with yours)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size = (50,10)))

# Initialize plotly subplots with shared x axis
rows = 5
cols = 2
fig = make_subplots(rows=rows, cols=cols, shared_xaxes=True,)

# Loop through subplots and add data to them
counter = 0
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(x=np.arange(0,50), y=df.iloc[:,counter], name=counter),
            row=(i+1), col=(j+1)
        )
        counter += 1
        
# Configure plot and show it        
fig.update_layout(height=800, width=800, title_text="Plotly Subplots with Custom Grid Lines")
fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=True, gridwidth=1, gridcolor='black')
fig.update_yaxes(showgrid=True, gridwidth=1, gridcolor='black')
fig.show()
```

With the following output:
[image: Plotly subplots]

If you prefer matplotlib for a more lightweight output, here's the same code:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size = (50,10)))

rows = 5
cols = 2
fig, axs = plt.subplots(rows, cols, figsize=(10,10))

counter = 0
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        axs[i, j].plot(df.iloc[:,counter], label=counter)
        axs[i, j].grid()
        axs[i, j].legend(loc='upper right')
        counter += 1
```

The nice thing with Plotly plots is that you can zoom in on various regions, control x/y axis bounds, and see exact data values when hovered over them!